# PHP adding a number value and text to a variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to edit Open Cart stock levels and I am just a beginner in php.

I am currently displaying the quantity of stock left (numeric only), which is stored within $product_info['quantity'].

```
$data['stock'] =  ($product_info['quantity']);
```

This works fine.

I am trying to add text to the end of the quantity so it would say for example 3 remaining in stock:

```
$data['stock'] =  ($product_info['quantity']) + "remaining in stock"; //(doesn't work)
```

I don't know the mark up to add text, I've tried a few things and no luck I can only get the number value to show.

Comment: In PHP, `+` is addition; `.` is concatenation

Comment: And you don't need any parenthesis like "(" or ")".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.` instead of `+`:

```
$data['stock'] =  ($product_info['quantity']) . "remaining in stock";
```

It is explained in the [String Operators entry](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) of the PHP Manual:

> There are two string operators. The first is the **concatenation**
>   **operator** ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left
>   arguments.